# Options for setting up a secure file transfer server

Tags: security, file-transfer, webserver

I need to set up a http server (which will have a valid ssh certificate) for securily sharing files between a company and many clients, with the following criterias:

- each client will have their own account, and each account will have a specific scope of files and rw permissions;
- it must have an "okay looking" appearence. I don't mean a page as beautiful as an Apple design, but something friendly enough for end users;
- it must be open-source.

The best option I have seen so far is nextcloud, but I coudln't find an easy way of setting up different user's scope of permissions. So I though I could receive some suggestions from you experts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution on nextcloud itself. It's not clear what it means at first, but once you test it you can see that working with users based on "group users" does satisfies all the conditions I need.